# Update Kendo UI scheduler datasource with remote data (Javascript)

Tags: json, kendo-ui, datasource, scheduler

I have some trouble with kendo ui scheduler component.

I'm getting my scheduler events from ms exchange via php exchange web services. Because of performance I don't want to load thousands of elements on calendar init.

Therefore I'm loading currents' week items only by default. On navigate event I want to update schedulers datasource.

My code is:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date(y+"/"+m+"/"+d),
    dateHeaderTemplate: kendo.template("<strong>#=kendo.toString(date, 'ddd, dd.MM.')#</strong>"),
    startTime: new Date(y+"/"+m+"/"+d+" 00:00 AM"),
    workDayStart: new Date(y+"/"+m+"/"+d+" 07:00 AM"),
    workDayEnd: new Date(y+"/"+m+"/"+d+" 8:00 PM"),
    height: 600,
    navigate: schedulerNavigate,
    views: [
        "day",
        "week",
        { type: "workWeek", selected: true },
        "month",
        "agenda"
    ],
    dataSource: {
        batch: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: myDataUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    }
    ...and some more options here...
});
```

"Naviagte" event calls schedulerNavigate() function:

```
function schedulerNavigate(e) {
    var
        scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler"),
        dataSourceUrl = myDataUrl+kendo.format("?view={1}&date={2:d}", e.action, e.view, e.date),
        dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: dataSourceUrl,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            }
    });

    // set datasource
    scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
}
```

When schedulerNavigate function is entered, the dataSource url is called, json will be returned. Everythings good so far... 
BUT: Url will be called twice! Schedulers' data  will be cleared but new data won't be set.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Philip

Comment: I'm guessing that the `navigate` event triggers a read of the widget's datasource automatically. Have you tried `e.preventDefault()`, set the new dataSource, and then triggered a `dataSource.read()` manually in your `schedulerNavigate` function?

Comment: Hey Brett. Tried your solutions and added `e.preventDefault();` to the first line of schedulerNavigate function. Also I added `scheduler.dataSource.read();` behind the setDataSource command. Unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you please mark my reply as an answer? That way, people who find the question using Google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired behavior you should enable "serverFiltering" option of the Scheduler and use the dataSource "transport.parameterMap" function to include the current view start/end time to the request:

```
dataSource: {
serverFiltering: true,
transport: {

    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {                        

        if (operation === "read") {
            var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

            var result = {
                start: scheduler.view().startDate(),
                end: scheduler.view().endDate()
            }

            return kendo.stringify(result);
        }

        return kendo.stringify(options);
    },
    //CRUD operations
```

Runnable demo with MVC backend:

- [KendoUI Scheduler Server Filtering](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/kendoui-scheduler-server-filtering)